# Google Chrome: automatically "Reveal in navigator"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to tell Chrome to automatically "Reveal in navigator" when you open a file from the "Source"tab inside DevTools?

Comment: No. But it'd be good if you [tell Chrome developers](https://crbug.com) to add this feature.

Comment: Opened an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=556508

Comment: I've starred the issue. Hopefully more people will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile you can enable it in chrome default settings.[image]

Comment: and now we can use dev tool as ide